# Salesforce URL Hacking

Tags: url, salesforce

I have an object with many record types, and I need to populate some fields on it whenever it is created.

For example, I have an object called "CustomObj" with a field called "CustomF" with these 2 Record Types "RecType1" and "RecType2".

On the creation of a new "CustomObj" I need to populate the field the "CustomF" by "Hello" when the record type is "RecType1" 
and by "Bye" when the record type is "RecType2"

Can I do that using the URL Hacking or I have to create 1 visualforce page to select the record type then redirect to the standard page with the values to populate this field or there is another approach?

What is the best practice?

How can I know the RecordType selected from the url itself ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by an Workflow Rule. Go to Setup->Create->Workflow & Approvals. Than u can choose your object on which u want to set up the workflows. Most of the part should be straightforward since all the steps are well documented.
So one rule would be like:
If Record Type == RecType1 than fill in Field XY with value ABC

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I know that but I need to populate them before creating the Record so the user can change them. But the goal is to populate them before creating the record.

Answer (score 0):

I see.
This is also possible. Go to the object and than your field you want to fill in the value. Click on edit and use the formula editor.
You can use a rule like

```
IF( $RecordType.DeveloperName = 'RecType1', 'Value for this', '')
```

for the default value

Comment: hi @utm.  you should edit your first answer instead of creating a new one.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to add the recordtype as condition in the url but it takes it as null because the user did not select the Record Type yet.

Comment: I do not understand why u want to use URLs for this? From my point of view (and this is also standard SF behaviour), if you have different Record Types for an Object and the user wants to create such an object the first thing the user must choose is an record type and after this the next page shows the standard record creation page

Comment: yes but I need to prepopulate values on the layout based on the RecordType before creating any record.So when the page is opened values should be populated before adding any other value or changing them and save the record.

Comment: And that is exectly what my answer is doing. When u chose a record type on the "first" page and than click -OK the next page (record creation page) appears. But when u than click on cancel-no record will be created

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce does not provide an option to override "continue" button on record type selection page. but you can override "new" button. So you can do the following

1. Override "New" button to move to a record type selection page, which
   will be a custom vf page (use radio buttons, description etc.).
2. The submit button (u can name as "Continue", just to imitate) should redirect to the standard page of data entry. But the
   URL will be custom made.
3. You can refer to this Blog (Saurabh's Salesforce Blog) - http://writeforce.blogspot.in/2012/12/prepopulating-fields-using-url-hacking.html - for the idea of how the URL hacking can be done as per your need. Here you need to identify the field id and use them in the URL to provide a value to be prepopulated.